# Firebase Query executing order isn't right

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase and I need to check if the username exists,
I use `Query` to check all the usernames and if I found the same username it won't continue to create the account.
but for some reason, the `Query` executed, even though I can in the debugger that it enters the query, maybe the query executed at the end or something, not as the order of the code.

Hope you can help me, 
here is a snippet of my code:

by the way, the snippet is in an AlertDialog if that's matter.

```
  btnCreate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    errorFlag = 0;

                    txtNote = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.note);
                    txtEmailReg = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtEmailReg);
                    txtPassReg = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtPassReg);
                    txtRepassReg = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtRepassReg);
                    txtUsernameReg = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);

                    final ArrayList<String> Users = new ArrayList<String>();
                    Query query = mDatabaseReference.child("users").orderByKey();
                    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                String userName = snapshot.getValue((User.class)).username;
                                Users.add(new String(userName));
                            }
                            if (Users.size() > 0) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < Users.size(); i++) {
                                    if (txtUsernameReg.getText().toString().equals(Users.get(i))) {
                                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "username exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                        errorFlag = 1;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }

                    });

                    if (errorFlag == 0) {
                        if (txtRepassReg.getText().toString().length() == 0 || txtEmailReg.getText().toString().length() == 0 || txtPassReg.getText().toString().length() == 0
                                || txtUsernameReg.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                            errorFlag = 1;
                            txtNote.setText("one empty field");
                        }

                        if (!(txtRepassReg.getText().toString().equals(txtPassReg.getText().toString()))) {

                            errorFlag = 1;
                            txtNote.setText("password doesn't match");
                        }

                        if (errorFlag == 0) {
                            CreateAcc(txtEmailReg.getText().toString(), txtPassReg.getText().toString(), dialog,
                                    txtUsernameReg.getText().toString());
                        }
                    }
                }


            });
```

Comment: From what I know about firebase it works with a event based subscription model for the data, so before the query gets the response (which happens asynchronously) the if block is reached and by then the value of errorFlag has not changed.

Comment: Are you storing usernames for the successful registered users in the firebase database? If yes, then I can suggest you a code which works as I have also done the same in my firebase project.

Comment: @IshanKhanna, as you described, so what can I do to fix that?